# Why do I NOT get warnings about uninitialized readonly fields?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

The C# compiler is kind enough to give you a "field is never assigned to" warning if you forget to initialize a readonly member which is private or internal, or if the class in which it is being declared is internal. But if the class is public, and the readonly member is public, protected or protected internal, then no warning for you!

Does anyone know why?

Sample code which demonstrates the conditions under which the warning is issued, and the conditions under which the warning is not issued:

```
namespace Test1 
{ 
    class Test1
    { 
#if TRY_IT 
        public readonly int m; //OK: warning CS0649: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 
        protected readonly int n; //OK: warning CS0649: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 
        internal readonly int o; //OK: warning CS0649: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 
        private readonly int p; //OK: warning CS0649: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 
        protected internal readonly int q; //OK: warning CS0649: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 

        Test1()
        {
            if( p != 0 ) //To avoid warning 'The field is never used'
                return;
        }
#endif
    } 

    public class Test2
    { 
#if TRY_IT 
        private readonly int m; //OK: warning CS0649: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 
        internal readonly int n; //OK: warning CS0649: Field is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0 

        Test2()
        {
            if( m != 0 ) //To avoid warning 'The field is never used'
                return;
        }
#endif 
        public readonly int o; //Blooper: no warning about field never assigned to. 
        protected readonly int p; //Blooper: no warning about field never assigned to. 
        protected internal readonly int q; //Blooper: no warning about field never assigned to.
    } 

    public sealed class Test3
    { 
        public readonly int m; //Blooper: no warning about field never assigned to. 
    } 
}
```

**EDIT:** For a moment you might think that the compiler refrains from issuing the warning in the case of public and protected members because it is reasonable to expect that derived classes might initialize the field. This theory does not hold any water for a number of reasons:

- An internal class may be subclassed, but the compiler does not
  refrain from issuing the warning in that case.
- The compiler fails to issue the warning even in the case of a sealed
  class, as Test3 in the sample code demonstrates.
- The warning makes sense for the sake of the integrity of the base
  class regardless of what a derived class may or may not do.
- A class is expressly prohibited by the language from initializing a
  readonly member of a base class. (Thanks, Jim Mischel.)

**EDIT2:** If my memory serves me well, Java gives all the proper warnings in all cases, regardless of whether the uninitialized final member is public, protected or private, and regardless of whether the class containing it is public or visible only within its package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual Studio null reference warning - why no error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413210/visual-studio-null-reference-warning-why-no-error)

Comment: @HenkHolterman nope, the two posts are definitely about different things.

Comment: Indeed, when I moved from Java to C# I was dismayed to learn that C# doesn't tell me when I forgot to initialize my readonly fields.  Perhaps non-nullable refs will help with this problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The short answer: this is an oversight in the compiler.

The longer answer: the heuristic which determines what warnings to issue for members and locals that are declared and never used, or written and never read, or read and never written, does not take the read-only-ness of the field into consideration. As you correctly note, it could, and thereby issue warnings in more cases. We could say that a public readonly field that is not initialized in any ctor "will always have its default value" for example.

I'll mention it to Neal in the new year and we'll see if we can improve those heuristics in Roslyn.

Incidentally, there are a number of situations in which a warning of this sort could be issued (regardless of read-only-ness) but we do not do so. I am not in my office today so I don't have my list of all those situations handy, but suffice to say there are a lot of them. It was stuff like "the field is declared as public and is in a public nested class of an internal class". In that situation the field is effectively internal and we can do the warning, but sometimes we do not.

One day many years ago I changed the heuristic so that *every* field that could be statically known to be unused produced a warning, and when that change made it into the internal version of the C# compiler that we use to compile the class libraries that are written in C#, all hell broke loose. Those guys always compile with "warnings as errors" turned on, and suddenly they started getting warnings on all kinds of fields that were deliberately initialized or used onl via reflection, and other dynamic techniques. I broke the build in a major way. Now, one might argue that hey, these guys should fix their code so that it suppresses the warning (and I did argue that) but ultimately it turned out to be easier to back the warning heuristic off to its previous level. I should have made the change more gradually.

Comment: Okay, this question has now been Lipperted.

Comment: As you said you write a heuristic, this means it's not possible to write exact algorithm? (e.g is NPC or n^10 which runs so slowly)? Also your heuristic (for knowing all warnings) was fast or slow? I mean programmer can see effect of that or not?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri in this case "heuristic" simply means "rule for making a decision". It is a hard rule, so it is not used in the same sense as they use it in the field of Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: @MikeNakis, Why should have heuristic rule? why do not have solid rules? because heuristic rules causes to fast algorithms, So if we can solve it with solid rule why we should have heuristic rules? and my question is this. (all AI heuristic algorithms run on heuristic rules).

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: The C# specification mostly does not specify how the compiler should produce warnings, only errors. (There are a few places where the spec requires warnings, but not many.) You want warnings to tell you about cases that are *legal* but *probably wrong*, and that's a difficult line to find sometimes. We therefore use heurstics -- guesses. There is no *exact* algorithm for identifying "legal code that does not do what the developer thinks it should do"; a warning is a guess *about the mental state of a person* and is therefore necessarily inexact.

Answer (score 4):

This is [MSDN Documentation: Compiler Warning (level 4) CS0649](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03b5270t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Field 'field' is never assigned to, and will always have its default
>   value 'value'
>
> The compiler detected an uninitialized private or internal field
>   declaration that is never assigned a value.

So, for non-internal and non-private fields you shouldn't expect to have a warning.

But I think the main reason is that C# compiler believes that you should initialize all the things that are accessible just from your assembly. I guess C# compiler left it to the others to initialize non-private and non internal fields in their assembly.

But I tested `protected internal` and I don't know why C# compiler doesn't warn about it.

Comment: Right. I know that. I am asking why.

Comment: @MikeNakis, I wrote my reason, In fact you should just initialize fields which are just accessible from your assembly. Seems it's a good rule.

Comment: Oh, it is a perfect rule to *always* initialize *all* fields, *especially* readonly ones. And that's why it would be nice if the compiler would always issue a warning if you forget to do that. But here the compiler doesn't.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for looking up the documentation.

Comment: @MikeNakis, IMO there is no need to initialize fields which can be initialized in other classes or assemblies, in fact in this case, you are not a creator, so there is no responsibility for you to initialize it. so no warning. Also about readonly or protected internal fields I think it will be too complicated and because of this C# compiler doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Good answer. Two comments. First, it didn't give the warning about `protected internal` because it's not `internal`. It's a *union* of `protected` and `internal`, so it's essentially the same as `protected`. And, regarding your last comment "no need to initialize fields which can be initialized in other classes or assemblies." A `readonly` field can only be assigned to by an initializer within the class where it's defined, or in the class's instance constructor. Inherited constructors can't assign to them.

Comment: @MikeNakis: I think what you're seeing here is the compiler's lack of special-casing of the assignment check when `readonly` is involved.

Comment: @JimMischel That's very interesting; if that's the case, then we might have an acceptable answer. Why don't you put this in an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @MikeNakis: I think Saeed's answer is the key. I just clarified things a little.

Comment: @JimMischel, Thanks for clarification and your humility.

Comment: @JimMischel When a question is asking "why is this done this way?" I think there is a fundamental difference between an answer which says "because the spec says so" and an answer which says "for no good reason, it is an omission".

Comment: Anyway, if @JimMischel does not want to add another answer, I can understand that. Then, Saeed, would you like to extend your answer to include Jim's explanation?

Comment: Oh, that's right. Hey, Saeed, do not get upset, I upvoted you.

Answer (score 1):

If it is public (or better not private) it can be used by another class outside your project. This is important to build libraries who should be used by others. If you would get a warning for every not used public property, field or method you wouldn't see the real problems.

Comment: I am not talking about unused members; I am talking about *uninitialized readonly* members. An uninitialized readonly member is practically useless to the class that declares it, and to every other class in the world.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the warning related to the scope and usage. Public and protected member can be accessed outside the assembly scope and by the class consumer, and the developer might actually want the value of the variable to be its default.

On the other hand, private and internal members are used internally, and you make it readonly because you do not want yourself to mistakenly change it, so it's highly likely that it should be initialised somewhere.

Comment: The thing is, they are not variables, because they are readonly. So, a member which will always contain its default value and will never change is useless. And to anyone who notices it, it looks very much like a bug. That's the kind of stuff warnings were invented for. If you do not want a warning, you can expressly initialize it with its default value, so as to document your intention. A halfway decent compiler will even optimize this initialization away.

Comment: If we really do the design, anything that made public got their own reason. For example, we might want to reserve the ability to change the value of that public field in the next version of our library without breaking current binary that depends on it. Anyway, it is not that I'm convinced that the warning, or lacking thereof, is appropriated. I'm just trying to do mind-guessing the MS people who made the decision so please don't expect that I'll defend or will be able to defend all that reasoning.