# Why not explicitly initialized readonly autoimplemented property is valid in c# 6?

Tags: c#, language-design, c#-6.0

**Update 1**
It seems like either my English is terribly awful, or people just don't give a sh... to understand what I'm asking about or simply look at the title of the post.

[C#5 specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) clearly states:

> Because the backing field is inaccessible, it can be read and written
>   only through the property accessors, even within the containing type.
>   This means that automatically implemented read-only or write-only
>   properties **do not make sense**, and are disallowed.

`public string MyProperty {get;}` has no sense, yet it costs nothing for compiler to emit getter not even warring about lacking setter. Backing field will be initialized with a default value. What does it mean? It means that designers **spent some effort** to implement a verification, to introduce functionality that could be left out.

Let's now consider C#6:

In C#6 the initialization of auto-implemented properties was [introduced](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

```
public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Jane";
```

or

```
public string FirstName { get; } = "Jane";
```

In the latter case property can be set in a constructor as well:

```
public class Program
{
    public string ImagePath { get; }

    public static void Main()
    {    
    }

    public Program()
    {
        ImagePath = "";
    }      
}
```

But only in constructor of the class where property was declared. Derived classes cannot set property's value.

Now ask yourself what this property means, if it was not initialized in constructor:

```
property string My {get;}
```

This is a 100% equivalent of C#5 prohibited property. It has no sense.
But such declaration being invalid in C#5 became valid in C#6. However semantics didn't change at all: this property is useless without explicit initialization.

That's why I am asking:

**Why not explicitly initialized readonly auto-implemented property is valid in c# 6?**

What I expect to see as an answer:

- Either debunking of my initial assumptions about changes in C#6
- Or the explanation of how and why compiler designers changed their mind
  about what makes sense, and what does not.

I find the answer `It's by design` to be completely irrelevant. It is just a fact. I look for reasons. I don't believe compiler designers decide on changes in behavior of compiler with just tossing the coin.

This is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689057/921054) of good answer.

**Original question**

In **VS2015** this code is compiled without errors:

```
public class Program
{
    public string ImagePath { get; }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

However, in **VS2013** I get error:

> Compilation error (line 5, col 28): 'Program.ImagePath.get' must
>   declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern.
>   Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set
>   accessors.

I know about initializable auto implemented properties, and in case of **VS2015** field gets default value, that is `null` here. But then it's interesting to know why this snippet was invalid in **C# 5**?

Initializable auto-implemented `readonly` property left without explicit initialization seems to me a bit ODD. It is likely a mistake rather than intention. I'd personally prefer compiler to require explicit initialization in this case:

`public string ImagePath { get; } = default(string);`

Ok, I know that such property can be also assigned in constructor:

```
public class Program
{
    public string ImagePath { get; }

    public static void Main()
    {    
    }

    public Program()
    {
        ImagePath = "";
        DoIt();
    }

    public void DoIt()
    {
        //ImagePath = "do it";
    }       
}

public class My : Program 
{
    public My()
    {
        //ImagePath = "asdasd";
    }
}
```

But if compiler can check that local variable is not initialized, the same is possible for the property.

So why is it as it is?

Comment: Why don't you ask then why compiler allows non-initialized readonly fields? It's exactly the same case.

Comment: @Evk If that behavior changed, I would ask.

Comment: Readonly properties is a new feature, so no behavior has changed. I mean this "It is likely a mistake rather than intention. I'd personally prefer compiler to require explicit initialization in this case" - is equally true for readonly fields.

Comment: @Evk Actually, readonly field can be changed through reflection. And with readonly field you know it's name, and that's an important detail.

Comment: So your question is really why the compiler doesn't complain about an unintialized property? I ask because you have very explicitly stated that your question is "Why not explicitly initialized readonly auto-implemented property is valid in c# 6?" yet this doesn't seem to be your focus in comments. Can you clarify what your question *really* is?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, my question is: "Why is it valid, and why does not C#6 compiler complain?"

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain about it because it is valid.  Why would the compiler complain about something that is valid?

Answer (score 5):

The compiler is telling you that automatic properties *must have both accessors defined*. For example, you could fix the error with

```
public string ImagePath { get; private set; }
```

assuming that you do not intend the property to be settable outside the class.

As to *why* you have to declare a setter or manually implement the property -- well, what good would be a property that you can read from, but will always return the default value of its type since there is no way to set it? Conversely, what good would be a property you can write to but can neither read from nor hook into its setter?

C# 6.0 gives you the option of having *write-once, read many* auto-properties; this is a huge difference as the value can be arbitrarily chosen, allowing you convenient syntax for properties with immutable values.

Comment: The question isn't so much why it's invalid C# 5, but why it's been made valid C# 6.

Comment: Adding onto this, getter-only auto-properties were not added until C# 6.0, hence why C#5 is yelling.
[Roslyn Github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#getter-only-auto-properties)

Comment: @hvd: Because in C# 6 you can select the value for a read-only property, which makes it actually useful. I added the last paragraph to explicitly mention this.

Comment: @AlexGravely Yep, but shouldn't C#6 also yell, if property was not initialized? Or the main reason was not initialization but the lack of setter? Interesting case, when not doing something is harder than doing. -No setter? No problem! Just, creating getter and initing backing field with default value. Here you are with useless property =)

Comment: The initialization discussion is a red herring and has nothing to do with why the compiler chooses to complain. All auto properties are initialized implicitly because their (hidden) backing fields are initialized on construction of an instance.

Comment: @vonorinp: The compiler isn't there to let you know if what you wrote is useless or not, it's there to validate that it's legal within the language specifications.

Comment: @AlexGravely. Yes, you are right, but specification usually aims at putting people in the pit of success.;)

Comment: @Jon Well, then I don't understand, how compiler works. When it sees get, it emits getter, when it sees set, it emits setter. But C#5 designers decided to make a check for both get and set. Isn't it harder than just independently emitting methods?!

Comment: @voroninp it's "harder" only in the mathematical sense. They check for both because if you don't have both the property you created is useless.

Comment: @Jon Yes, and autoiplemented not initialized read only property is useless as well. That's what I'm talking about. In C#5 they din't even make it possible, yet C#6 allows it.

Comment: @voroninp a) you can still assign in the constructor, so "useless" would need to check the constructor AST as well, and b) IIRC the designers felt that "you can save typing if you will just accept a private setter" was pushing people in the wrong direction when what they really wanted to do was have immutable properties. That is to say, "let's prevent useless" was a nice idea that they probably thought they could get for free, but it turned out that TAANSTAFL.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why your question have been down voted. This is interesting observation but please keep in mind that it is not a breaking change - it is just 'new functionality' that is 'leftover' of other functionality - initialization of auto-implemented properties.

That means it had no sense previously, but now it has.

Moreover, I think it has always had sense. E.g. when you have some base class or interface, for example

```
interface IPerson
{
    int Age { get; }
}
```

Some day you may want to implement null-object pattern where the age is irrelevant. In c#5 you have to write `public int Age { get { return 0; } }`, while in c#6 you can simply do `public int Age { get; }` or even transform interface to abstract class changing only its definition from `interface` to `abstract class`.

Comment: >  I think it has always had sense.  Actually, me too =) And we can ask why then they decided to do it in C# 5 in that way. I agree, my question is mostly about language design and its philosophy. That's why i like this [talk] (https://vimeo.com/154708153) by Bill Wagner. I'm always inspired by weighted prospective thinking of designers. Much to learn from them.