# Why does C# not warning about non-nullable long field?

Tags: c#, .net

Why do I not get a non-nullable warning (or some other warning) for FieldTwo not being set in the constructor? I'm using .Net 5.0 and `Nullable` option is set to true in the project file.

```cs
  public class MyClass
  {
    public string FieldOne;
    public long FieldTwo;

    public MyClass (string p1, long p2)
    {
      FieldOne = p1;
      // FieldTwo is not set. Where is the non-nullable warning!?
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to get a compiler warning here then? I don't want it to default to `0`, I want the compiler to force me to set the value from the parameter in the constructor function

Comment: `long `is a value type, it can never be null. You don't a nullability warning.  Those are fields, not properties, and the long-typed field's value is 0. You'd have to use long? to be able to store null. That would generate a [Nullable<long>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-5.0) field, which can accept null values

Comment: So there's literally no way for the compiler to tell the programmer that they've made a mistake and that they forgot to set the PropertyTwo field explicitly in the constructor?

Comment: Since `long` is not nullable, the usual rules for value types apply: it's initialized with `default` if you don't do anything in the constructor, meaning it ends up as `0`. This decision (and the decision to not require explicit initialization, or even warn about it) goes back all the way to the first version of C# and is orthogonal to nullability concerns (an application will not crash on accessing a `long` with value `0`, after all, though it may malfunction).

Comment: @cdimitroulas the real bug here is calling a field `Property`. Fields are implementation details. Yes, there are ways to require values in all properties, eg by using the `Required` attribute or, in C# 8 and later, by using a `record`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can probably find or write a roslyn analyzer which will moan at you if you don't explicitly initialize all fields

Comment: There are existing static analysis warnings for unused parameters, which also help -- this does not detect the case of `p2` being used but not to assign `FieldTwo`, of course.

Comment: What is the actual problem you want to solve? In validation scenarios it's better to use data annotations or validation rules, because a DTO may easily be in an invalid state during deserialization. Many serializers and a lot of Reflection code work by creating an instance then setting properties, and still fail with a `record` or a `class` without a default constructor. In other cases, you *do* want a `record` type to ensure everything is set and immutable

Comment: Panagiotis, I'm not trying to do anything beyond what is stated in the question, don't overcomplicate things. I just expected that in a statically typed language I would be able to have more guarantees that prevent programmer errors. But it seems that due to the `default` value initialization for value types, C# loses some safety and programmers need to just be aware of this odd behaviour

Comment: @cdimitroulas use `record` then. This has nothing to do with static typing or safety.

Comment: Of course it does, in other languages I can have the compiler force me to correctly initialize a field in a class instead of getting some arbitrary 0 default value.

Comment: The compiler now does [warn you if you don't initialise a readonly field](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLAChUGIB2BXCECGARhAKYAEJmRpqqZZMAzA3GQLICeAwgQM690yAb0H0ATiXwATAPaYIHMhDkBzMgH0ADmJmaSY4BwAqAdxkBuUfTJWmDBAAYyABR16DHAPKYSllNYZmZUw1V119Q1MZMgBeAD4NbXCPKL9bZk4efH4yAAoYRzJNBAAaJVUiuABKKxF/AJc3CK8fWKKEPwayAHpuxuTIszIwXjJMGWAyXhJgADoyAHUAC31yEbJgFbG5AFocPGpyE3wxTDAQgEIAfisAX0FboA==).

Comment: @cdimitroulas again, a field is an implementation detail, just a place to keep some data between methods. There may not be any valid value to store there at first, and `0` is as good a value as `null` for reference types. This is well known, not some confusing behavior. It's *properties* that are part of the type's contract and need to be always valid. That's why they exist, with getters and setters to validate values and ensure only valid values are stored.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I'm relatively new to C#. Could you elaborate why an extra field is needed to get this readonly field warning (`_propertyTwo`)? I can't just set FieldTwo to readonly, otherwise I don't get the warning

Comment: @cdimitroulas it's not an extra *field*. It's the backing field for the property. Why do you want to use fields instead of properties? What language are you having in mind? It's clear you're trying to use the concepts of another language. C++ doesn't behave this way. Neither does Javascript. F# and Typescript, only in specific cases. *Functional* languages are far stricter than static languages in this respect.  Both TypeScript and C# were created by the same person, so it's not that the C# designer didn't know better. `strictPropertyInitialization` was added in TS 2.7

Comment: When researching about fields vs properties I learned about the AutoProperty feature in C#. I didn't know about this before and this changed how I understand what I'm writing in my own code in C#. Thanks for your insights

Comment: It is a bit annoying that the compiler doesn't warn you if you don't initialise a get-only property. Obviously Resharper warns you, but that costs extra money!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`long` is a value type and cannot be null. So there is no reason for warn about null. What I suspect you want is a field not initialized warning.

If a private field is never assigned, it causes a CS0649 warning. However,  if the field public, or is modified anywhere in the class, this warning is not raised. For example, the following would be perfectly acceptable code, and should not give a warning:

```
public class MyClass{
    private long myLong;
    public void Increment() => myLong++;
}
```

If the field should only be set from the constructor you should declare it as readonly. However, public readonly fields does not trigger a warning, even if they probably should. See [Why do I NOT get warnings about uninitialized readonly fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688204/why-do-i-not-get-warnings-about-uninitialized-readonly-fields).

Comment: Note that if you declare the property as get-only, then the compiler DOES warn you if it's unassigned: `public long PropertyTwo { get; }`

Comment: @MatthewWatson [Really?](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxANwKYCcoDMCecAmIA1AD4CwAUAAIBMAjJZQMQwCuANuxMO6gASoY3Xowp8+VAMwSafALI4AwlwDOKyuIDeG8ROlU6ABj4AFdAHsADhgQ4A8jFQBuHeKl925mAHNTF6+i2ACoA7uZ8mnzeqAhOfAC+orp68kqqKnwAFAbGlnRwHl6+ljQAlK4RFeJmVjb2jnwAvHx5LmLJfAD0nX61gTih4VAZMOYIfCoxAHR8AOoAFhj8w3wIi3yjMAC0bJzC/CEQ6DCw3gCEAPwVie3xQA=)

Comment: No, I just tested it. I don't get a warning

Comment: Oh, it must be a Resharper warning. EDIT: Yes, I just checked. Resharper warns you. Resharper also warns you if you don't assign a readonly long.

Comment: And also if you're using a readonly field, the built-in Code Analysis also warns you: `Warning CS0649 Field 'MyClass._propertyTwo' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value 0` - so there's that possibility too.

Comment: So the answer is: [If you use a readonly field, you WILL get a warning](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLAChUGIB2BXCECGARhAKYAEJmRpqqZZMAzA3GQLICeAwgQM690yAb0H0ATiXwATAPaYIHMhDkBzMgH0ADmJmaSY4BwAqAdxkBuUfTJWmDBAAYyABR16DHAPKYSllNYZmZUw1V119Q1MZMgBeAD4NbXCPKL9bZk4efH4yAAoYRzJNBAAaJVUiuABKKxF/AJc3CK8fWKKEPwayAHpuxuTIszIwXjJMGWAyXhJgADoyAHUAC31yEbJgFbG5AFocPGpyE3wxTDAQgEIAfisAX0FboA==). Looks like it was fixed at some point in the 10 years since the question linked from the answer above was posted.

Comment: @Matthew Watson, I updated the answer. Looks like private fields raises the warning, regardless of readonly or not, but public fields does not, even if the public field is readonly. At least in .net 4.8.

Answer (score 1):

`long` is a value type and can't be null. Value types are always initialized when declared with a default value, in this case `0`. You'd have to change the *field* type to `long?` if you wanted to store a `null`

Those fields aren't properties anyway. This isn't just semantics. Fields are implementation details, even public fields. They aren't considered part of a class's API surface. Properties *are* part of the API, they get serialized by default by all serializers (fields don't) and guarantee In fact having public fields is a code smell.

To ensure all *properties* are initialized you can use a `record` type instead of a `class` :

```
public record(string PropertyOne, long PropertyTwo);
```

This generates a class with init-only properties for `PropertyOne` and `PropertyTwo` and a constructor that requires values for all properties. Along with equality operators, deconstructors and a `ToString()` implementation that returns all properties in the form of a JSON string.

Comment: I'm kind of baffled by the fact "public fields" is even an allowed thing in C#...